# IVP Subsitution inside Initial Equation

Tags: differential-equations

Apologies if this is a duplicate; I am new to Mathematica and have been searching through the forums, though can't seem to find what I am looking for. Below is a hypothetical example:

```
eqA = D[y[t],t] == t^2 +y[1]+y[0];
DSolve[{eqA},y[t],t]
```

Where I would like y[1] to really be y[t, when t=1], and the same for y[0]. Currently when I am running DSolve, Mathematica assumes y[1] and y[0] to be separate variables not related to t. I would also prefer to set the value of y[1] == 0 (for example), though am unsure of where to do such. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) ? Is this what you need? `DSolve[
 {
  D[y[t], t] == t^2,
  y[1] == 0
  }, y[t], t]` Where `y[1]==0` is the border condition, and it means that when `t==1` then `y[t]==0` .

Comment: In this case Mma understands `y[1]` exactly as ` y[t, when t=1]`. The other question, if Mma "knows" the solution of such an equation.

Comment: I think you meant to write `DSolve[{eqA}, y[t], t]`, not `DSolve = [{eqA}, y[t], t]` . Please correct you post.

Answer (score 1):

This equation can be solved, but informally. Let us rewrite is as follows:

```
ds = DSolve[{D[y[t], t] == t^2 + a + b, y[1] == a}, y[t], t]

(*  {{y[t] -> 1/3 (-1 - 3 b + 3 a t + 3 b t + t^3)}}  *)
```

Now let us take the solution in, say, point t=0 and equate it b:

```
s = Solve[b == ds[[1, 1, 2]] /. t -> 0][[1, 1]]

(*  b -> -(1/6)  *)
```

Substitution of this into the solution yields

```
ds /. s

(*  {{y[t] -> 1/3 (-(1/2) - t/2 + 3 a t + t^3)}}  *)
```

Now let us check the solution:

```
1/3 (-(1/2)-t/2+3 a t+t^3)/.t->0
(*  -(1/6)  *)

1/3 (-(1/2)-t/2+3 a t+t^3)/.t->1
(*  a  *)
```

Here a plays the role of the arbitrary constant of the solution.

Have fun!